# WPF GridViewColumn.CellTemplate DataTemplate ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, datagridviewcolumn, contentpresenter

I have a ListView which uses DataTemplates. If i use this in a ListView defined the columns over XAML it works how it schould. My DataTemplates are used in my view. But if i want to use the same DataTemplates in a second ListView, where i add new columns to the ListView it does not use my DataTemplate. What should i Do?

The code in XAML for the first ListView looks like this:

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="lvSecondColumn" Header="Value" Width="200">
   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

My Code i use for generating a column in second ListView is:

```
DataColumn dc = (DataColumn)colum;

GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn( );
column.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding( dc.ColumnName ) );
column.Header = dc.ColumnName;
TestColumns.Columns.Add( column );

TestListView.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

In WPFInspector i see there is no ContentPresenter in my dynamic Generated Column.
[Picture from missing ContentPresenter from WPFInspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6Uak.png)
How to add the ContentPresenter to my dynamic column???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set both Binding and DataTemplate. According to the docs
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.displaymemberbinding(v=vs.110).aspx

> The following properties are all used to define the content and style
>   of a column cell, and are listed here in their order of precedence,
>   from highest to lowest:
>   - DisplayMemberBinding
>   - CellTemplate
>   - CellTemplateSelector

If you use binding then it will generate a textbox with a ".ToString()" of the bound object. If you are aware of the structure of your items in the ListView you can just make DataTemplates with appropriate bindings in it. However when generating columns dynamically this is an issue.

You can dynamically generate a datatemplate for your column and integrate the binding in it:

```
public DataTemplate CreateColumnTemplate(string property)
{
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(
    @"<DataTemplate 
        xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""> 
            <ContentPresenter Content=""{Binding " + property + @"}""/> 
        </DataTemplate>");
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;
}
```

Then you can generate your columns like this:

```
GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn( );
column.CellTemplate = CreateColumnTemplate(dc.ColumnName);
column.Header = dc.ColumnName;
TestColumns.Columns.Add( column );
```

I didn't run the code there may be little mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And this is correct. For this i have used 2 ListViews for testing. The one where i use the Binding from XAML and it works. The other ListView designs the columns at Runtime and this does not work correct. It only generates a Textbox with a ".ToString()" content. But i want in the dynamic Textbox also my DataTemplate used. Not the default Text box. So how to set the <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/> in code?

Comment: You can dynamically compile data templates per column using xamlReader. I added it into the answer.

Comment: Many thanks to you Dmitry. There were any further issues to solve. So it took more time as expected. But it works like i want now . The hint with the XamlReader.Load was the key for me. I did not know this way to implement XAML into Code.